# Replace two arrays items having some conditional statement

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

There are two arrays of images of 28*28 pixels giving mask values like this. Image1 is showing left mask of lung and Image2 is showing the right mask of the lung.  After reshaping these images results are of this type

```
img1=[............,False,  True, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False,  True,  True,..................]
img2=[.........................,True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
   False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
   False, False, False, False,............................]
```

Basically, I want to merge these two masks to make 1 mask that would be a new_image and which show a combines result of left and right masks. What I thought is replace the index values of img2 where it's showing True in Img1. Here  is my code

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
img1=Image.open(path)
img2=Image.open(path)
img1_array=np.asarray(img1)
img2_array=np.asarray(img2)
img1_array_reshape=img1_array.reshape(784)
img2_array_reshape=img2_array.reshape(784)
print(len(img1_array_reshape))
print(len(img2_array_reshape))

indices=[i for i,val in enumerate(img2_array_reshape) if val==True]
print(indices)
for index in indices:
    print(index)
    img1_array_reshape[indices[index]] = img2_array_reshape[index]
```

But I am not able to run the last line,Is there any direct way to do that ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `img1 | img2`?  Can you post a small sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to combine those two arrays with `True`, then you can use `zip`.

```
a = [True,False,False]
b = [True,True,True]

combined = [i[0] or i[1] for i in zip(a,b)]

print(combined) //[True, True, True]
```

Comment: I'd recommend not doing this, since the arrays are already given as `np.ndarray` and not as `list`s. Thus boolean masking is the cleaner, faster and more pythonic approach.

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using a boolean mask to index cells in `img2_array` which are `True` in `img1_array`:

```
img1 = Image.open(path)
img2 = Image.open(path)
img1_array = np.asarray(img1)
img2_array = np.asarray(img2)
img2_array[img1_array] = True
```

Since `img1_array` seems to already be an array of `dtype=bool`, you can use it as an index array directly.
This avoids slow and complicated looping as well as creating complicated `indices` by reshaping and list comprehension.
If you want to reshape your images anyways, you can still do `img1_array_reshape = img1_array.reshape(-1)`. This works before applying the boolean masked operation and also afterwards.

Comment: Sorry but it does not take img1 and img2 as of type bool but of Image type @Scotty1-

Comment: You should clarify this in your question by posting a minimum working example of correct inputs. Otherwise it is impossible to solve your problem.

Comment: Why the downvote? My answer is correct for the information that was provided. If the information provided is not correct, I cannot do some wizardry and guess the correct answer. Also the answer of Leogoesger is not recommended. I stated the reasons above. If will not provide an efficient code if you have more and/or larger images.